# Reading PNG Files from Javascript - the argument is not a blob

Tags: javascript, cordova, filereader

Trying to read a `.png`-File with Javascript FileReader

```
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {

    for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        try {
            reader.readAsDataURL(entries[i]);
            reader.onload = doOnload(entries[i].name);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert (e.message);
        }
    }
});
```

What I get is

> Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is  not a Blob.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself:

```
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {

   for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        var entry = entries[i]; 
        entry.file(function(file){
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = doOnload(entry.name);
        });
    }
});
```